# Managing with several remotes

Tags: git, heroku, git-remote

I've just deployed my Django project to Heroku, and now I have `git remote -v`

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/lyf2000proj.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/lyf2000proj.git (push)
```

remotes.
But I wanna to also have project in GitHub, but I do not know hot to better do this. I mean I wanna make some alters in `GitHub` remote and after tests also push changes to `heroku` remote.

That could be as follows:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'commit'

git push github master
OR
git push heroku master
```

### UPDATE

I've past

```
git add remote github <url>
```

Well, after this iI've also made

```
git push -u github master
```

And now I'd have to two masters from different remotes. But when I'm using

```
git branch
* master
```

There's only one branch. And after I've made commit and used using

```
git push heroku master
```

The information list is still was telling me that I have not pushed commit.

Answer (score 0):

> But I wanna also have a project in GitHub, but I do not know how to do this

Create a new repository on GitHub and ad it ads remote

```
# add the second remote
git remote add github <url>

# Now you can push to any remote you wish
git push github <branch>
git push heroku <branch>
```

---

#### `git branch`

`git branch` shows you only the local branches, add the `-a` flag to see all the bracnhes

`git branch -a`

Comment: Ok, I made it, but still have some questions in update)

Comment: execute this and you will see all your branches:

`git branch -a`